# django multi db routing doesnt work with multiple schemas

Tags: django, oracle, orm, django-models, django-orm

I have django running on oracle backend. I need to use two schemas - one for a legacy DB, second one for all django related tables.

So this is my settings.DATABASES:

```
APPS_DB = 'apps'
DATABASES = {

    'default' : { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle'
        'NAME': 'django',                      
        'USER': 'django-tables',                      
        'PASSWORD': '****',                  
        'HOST': 'localhost',                       
        'PORT': '1531',                     
    },

    APPS_DB : { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle', 
        'NAME': 'django',                      
        'USER': 'legacy-stuff',                      
        'PASSWORD': '****',                 
        'HOST': 'localhost',                     
        'PORT': '1531',                      
     },
}
```

I also defined router:

```
class MyRouter(object):
    """A router to control all database operations on models"""

def __init__(self):
    aux = []
    for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        if not app.endswith('myapp'):
            aux.append(app)
    self.djangoStuff = tuple(map(lambda x: x[x.rfind('.')+1:], aux))

def is_django_stuff(self, model):
    return model._meta.app_label in self.djangoStuff

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    "Point all django apps models to separate DB"
    logger.info("READ from " + model._meta.app_label)
    if self.is_django_stuff(model):
        logger.info("Will be directed to default DB")
        return None
    logger.info("Will be directed to legacy DB")    
    return settings.APPS_DB

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    "Point all django apps models to separate DB"
    logger.info("WRITE")
    if self.is_django_stuff(model):
        return None
    return settings.APPS_DB

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    "Allow any relation"
    logger.info("ALLOW REL")
    return True

def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
    "Allow syncdb for all managed objects"
    logger.info("ALLOW SYNC")
    if db == 'default' and self.is_django_stuff(model):
        return True
    if db != 'default' and not self.is_django_stuff(model):
        return True
    return False
```

Now I have very simple model:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

I make two syncdbs:

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py syndb --database apps
```

Everything goes fine.
Then I create poll object using 'python manage.py shell'

```
superuser = User.objects.all()[0]
p = Poll(question="foo", user = superuser, pub_date = datetime.now())
p.save()
```

And I try to retrieve user from poll:

```
  a = Poll.objects.all()
  b = len(a)
  b = a[0]
  c = b.artist
```

I have logging enabled in router so I see that last query will be directed to correct DB:

```
READ from myapp
Will be directed to apps DB
READ from myapp
Will be directed to apps DB
READ from auth
Will be directed to default DB
```

I can even see actual SQL statement:

```
(0.005) SELECT "AUTH_USER"."ID", "AUTH_USER"."USERNAME", "AUTH_USER"."FIRST_NAME",    "AUTH_USER"."LAST_NAME", "AUTH_USER"."EMAIL", "AUTH_USER"."PASSWORD", "AUTH_USER"."IS_STAFF", "AUTH_USER"."IS_ACTIVE", "AUTH_USER"."IS_SUPERUSER", "AUTH_USER"."LAST_LOGIN", "AUTH_USER"."DATE_JOINED" FROM "AUTH_USER" WHERE "AUTH_USER"."ID" = :arg0 ; args=(1,)
```

But I'm getting error:

```
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 350, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 361, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 85, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 763, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 675, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

So my question is - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Django isn't equipped to handle multiple schema, sadly. I think this is changing in 1.5 and forward. There is a patch somewhere to handle this, I looked into this a couple months back - but ended up just using two seperate DBs on the same server.

Comment: @JamesR - Yeah, I think you are right.  I looked into this too.  I really hope that Django 1.5 will address this issue.  Having different schemas in a database is really common.  I have always felt this was a real weakness in django.

Comment: If something works with two separate DBs it should work with two schemas - at lease in Oracle case. I know there is no support for multiple schemas in django, that's why I decided to use multi-db approach. I just don't understand why I'm getting this error because it's on database level so it's not django who is preventing cross DB relations. On the othere hand looking at the quesry oracle have no idea about any relation going here.

Comment: First of all the error is not from django but from database.
Secondly I'm not using different databases but different schemas so
relations are possible.
The error has nothing to do with foreign key or any relation.
It just looks like django is ignoring router suggestion and directs
sql query to wrong DB.

Comment: Your return statements are settings.APPS_DB. In my router, I return a string, so in your case return APPS_DB (and be certain to import that variable). Besides, I don't think settings.APPS_DB is valid in any event, the database is stored in the dictionary located at settings.DATABASES

Comment: I'm sorry I've omitted this fragment of code. settings.APPS_DB is just a string: APPS_DB = 'apps'. So for this problem you can assume there is no settings.APPS_DB but a simple string 'apps'.

Comment: Anyway, look what is the real problem here. Noete the query that needs to be executed. This doesn't contain any joins. The only problem is that this perfectly correct query is send to wrong schema although the router suggests a good one.
I don't know why, is there anyone who can explain this to me?

Comment: are your settings correct?

        'NAME': 'django',                      
        'USER': 'django-tables',      

should be perhaps:

        'USER': 'django',                      
        'NAME': 'django-tables',

Comment: Yes, they are. I just changed them not to expose a password etc. but you can assume I checked connection details and all that is fine.

Comment: Sir, are you sure you are using the right names for the schemas? Because your code displays the same name for both the schemas!

Comment: The name is indeed the same, but the user is different so these two users are able to see only their own tables.

Comment: I misunderstood your issue as being one where Django's lack of multi-schema support was the problem, rather than cross-DB foreign keys. But I think @GeorgeLund is right below... this appears to be a cross-DB foreign key issue and his answer applies. (Note the "cannot really be an FK" part -- that's key, it should just be a uniquely-indexed integer field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-database foreign keys are essentially invalid, because Django is modelling a "proper" relational database with referential integrity, and that can't be enforced at database level if the models are stored in completely different physical stores.

Anyway, for that reason Django must assume that any objects exist in the same database as the one you originally retrieved. In your case, it got your Poll object from your legacy database, so it must look for your user (or artist or whatever it is) there too.

For simple queries like this it's very easy to work around, for example:

```
poll = Poll.objects.all()[0]
user_id = poll.user_id # _id after the name of your "Foreign Key" field - which cannot really be an FK
user = User.objects.get(user_id) # This will be a new query and can use a different database, it will check the router
```

For more complex queries (joins etc) you will often find that you need to build lists or sets of ids, and do queries using filter(id__in=your_list_of_ids).

Depending on the number of records, there may be performance or memory usage penalties for doing this. (But in some cases your queries will actually be much faster than the original joins, at all depends on your application.) You might need to break up your lists of id's into batches or your queries may become too long, etc etc. But none of these problems are insurmountable.

When you are dealing with id's from another database, it's up to you to enforce referential integrity. Sometimes you need to set up batch processes to deal with tidying up the data.

This all makes it sounds wrong, but such separation of concerns, particularly if you can keep the dependencies limited, and in just one direction, can be exactly the right approach.